# Join two colors together only where they overlap

Tags: glsl

I'm trying to display a mouse touch indicator as a circle.

So far I was able to product a vertical and horizontal bar (as x and y touch indicator) which cross each other forming a cross shape.  I would like to form a circle from where they intersect.

```
...

float touchX = u_TouchX;
float touchY = u_ResolutionX - u_TouchY;

float smoothTouchXS = smoothstep( u_ResolutionY - touchX - 300.0, u_ResolutionY- touchX,  gl_FragCoord.y );
float smoothTouchXE = smoothstep( u_ResolutionY - touchX, u_ResolutionY - touchX + 300.0, gl_FragCoord.y );

float smoothTouchYS = smoothstep( u_ResolutionX - touchY - 300.0, u_ResolutionX- touchY,  gl_FragCoord.x );
float smoothTouchYE = smoothstep( u_ResolutionX - touchY, u_ResolutionX - touchY + 300.0, gl_FragCoord.x );

float finalC =  ( smoothTouchXS - smoothTouchXE ) + ( smoothTouchYS - smoothTouchYE ));
photo.r     += finalC;
gl_FragCoord = photo.r
```

This line is wrong:

```
float finalC =  ( smoothTouchXS - smoothTouchXE ) + ( smoothTouchYS - smoothTouchYE ));
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to sum both bars together, so that if both of them contain color, only then an output color would be produced in the end resulting in the circle in the center of these two bars.

What is the proper function to sum the two bars together, so that the result is only returned if they both overlap? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to form a circle from where they intersect.

Starting with your code, the easiest solution is to multiply the "smooth" touch from the x and y axis instead of sum them:

```
float finalC =  (smoothTouchXS - smoothTouchXE) * (smoothTouchYS - smoothTouchYE);
```

See the preview, where `(smoothTouchXS - smoothTouchXE) * (smoothTouchYS - smoothTouchYE)` is put on top of `(smoothTouchXS - smoothTouchXE) + (smoothTouchYS - smoothTouchYE)`;

[image: sum versus multiply]

One further possibility is to calculate "smooth" offset to the "touch" point on the x and y axis. Then find the maximum offset and use the inverse result (1.0 - offset). This solution would form a **rectangle**:

```
const float max_dist = 300.0;

vec2  touch      = vec2(u_TouchX, u_ResolutionY - u_TouchY);
vec2  touch_dist = abs(touch - gl_FragCoord.xy);

vec2  smootTouch = smoothstep(0.0, max_dist, touch_dist);
float finalC     = max(0.0, 1.0-max(smootTouch.x, smootTouch.y));
```

[image: rectangle]

Another possibility is to use the distance to the "touch" point, which would form a **circle**:

```
const float max_dist = 300.0;

vec2  touch      = vec2(u_TouchX, u_ResolutionY - u_TouchY);
vec2  touch_dist = abs(touch - gl_FragCoord.xy);

float smootTouch = smoothstep(0.0, max_dist, length(touch_dist));
float finalC     = max(0.0, 1.0-smootTouch);
```

[image: circle]

Comment: Thank you so much!!